# Center align items and then hide few them but still remain center aligned

Tags: css

I have center aligned 3 svg's. The user selects which of them gets displayed from backend and the rest are hidden. I want to keep these images center aligned. Right now if one or more images are hidden, it lefts empty space for that area. I am using opacity to hide the items
Code:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="work--service_provided">
  1
  </div>
  <div class="work--service_provided" style="display:none;">
  2
  </div>
    <div class="work--service_provided">
  3
  </div>
</div>
.work--service_provided{
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eret23y8/1/).

Comment: @TehTris: done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two way of doing it:

1. add the following to your css

   .parent{
     text-align: center;
   }

https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/eret23y8/4/

2. add align="center" to your parent

`<div class="parent" align="center">`

https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/eret23y8/3/